# Filter today's dated data with Flask-sqlalchemy (convert from YYYY-MM-DD-HH: MM: SS format to YYYY-MM-DD without hours, minutes and seconds)

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter where the creation date equals today.
Consider the following function:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func
from datetime import date

def attempt_count(user_id):    
    r = db_session.query(RecoveryToken)\
                  .filter(RecoveryToken.user_id == user_id)\
                  .filter(func.date(RecoveryToken.created_at) == date.today()).all()
    number = len(r)
    print('todays records', number)
    return number
```

**Models.py**

```py
created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True,default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz))
```

I am trying to filter where the creation date equals today. The problem I have is that the database records are in this format: `2021-09-07 20:11:18.000`. What is the best approach to compare these values without thinking about the different formats.

Comment: What is the type of `RecoveryToken.created_at`? Please add your model.

Comment: created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True,default=datetime.datetime.now(tz=tz))

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer and it worked for me. I had to use date and cast

```py
from sqlalchemy import cast, Date
from datetime import date

def attempt_count(user_id):    
    r = db_session.query(RecoveryToken).filter(RecoveryToken.user_id == '278e407bc3904dd18acf0dc9196834c4').filter(RecoveryToken.created_at.cast(Date) == date.today()).all()
    print(r)
    number = len(r)
    print('todays records', number)
    return number
```

Answer (score 0):

try .date() :

```
.filter(RecoveryToken.created_at.date() == date.today())
```

.date() return the Date of DateTime field